# Could you please help me identifying this abstract font ("MICROBREWERY")?

Tags: font-identification

It was a free font from the web. Do not remember the site. I have already used Identifont and WhatTheFont! to find it. All I have found is similar fonts. It is being used for a cooler sign.
Please help me identifying this font. Look at the letter "R".

[image: MICROBREWERY sample text]

Comment: The wonkier the font, the more likely it exists up on Dafont. I'd peruse the options over there.

Answer (score 5):

The font is called 400ML and is supposedly designed by Marco Terre

[image: 400ML]

The original article for the font is not found: [www.okilla.com/521/resource-typography-400ml-type/](http://www.okilla.com/521/resource-typography-400ml-type/)

However you can view a [web archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20150316110845/http://www.okilla.com/521/resource-typography-400ml-type/) of the font post.

> TERMS OF USE:
>
> You have the right to use the font for personal and commercial
>   projects.
>
> You DO NOT have the right to redistribute for free or for sale in any
>   format without my prior consent.
>
> You may NOT use my font in any software or apps without my prior
>   consent.

The font and license can be found and downloaded here. https://github.com/nullgorithm/fonts/blob/master/400ml-type.zip

Comment: It's probably abandon-ware at this point. The only things that pops up are pintrest posts when you google 400ML Marco Terre. How did you even find this at all?

Comment: @LateralTerminal. Maybe it was easier to find back in 2015. Do you need this font? if I google "400ML font", the first result is a github repository which contains the font. The [parent folder](https://github.com/nullgorithm/fonts/blob/master/400ml-type.zip) contains the entire font and a license. The license says the front is free for both personal and commercial use, but may not be redistributed, (which is kind of what happened when I downloaded the zip).

Comment: @Wolff that exact wording does give me a github repository. I made a suggested edit to the answer.